# Yii - Javascript evaluation as parameter in AjaxButton

Tags: javascript, php, yii

Im a newbie in Yii and Im not sure Im doing things in the right way. I've tried searching here, on Yii Forum or google but I can't found an answer.

**Situation**

I have to add dynamically a code to the page calling a specific Action in Controller that need a single parameter.

```
public function actionAddRow($index)
    {
        $model = new Users();
        $this->renderPartial('_usersBatchRow', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'i'=>$index,
                'countries' => Countries::model()->findAll(),
        ),false,false);
    }
```

This action works fine and the partialTemplate does what I need.

To call this, in the main page I use:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Add Something",
        CController::createUrl('users/AddRow'),
                array(
                      'method'=>'get',
                      'data'=>array('index'=>'2'),  
                      'success'=>'function(data){                                             
                      $("#tableBody").append(data);
                                        }'));
```

The result of action is perfectly added to table. 
As you can see, I've hardcoded value "2" in parameters settings.

I need this value is retrieved dynamically reading, with javascript, an hidden field.

I've tried this approach but it doesn't works:

```
'data'=>array('index'=>"js:$('#hiddenValue').val();"),
```

The hiddenValue is updated in 'success' section (not yet in the code above) so the next one will pass the new value to the action.

Is this an exact approach or Im doing things in the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: The PHP code is run server side, so won't have access to any javascript at the point it builds the button. You'll probably need some javascript code to manipulate the html of the button once it's rendered

Comment: Yeah. That code is create one time only. Your answer has put me in the right way. The CHtml command creates an hidden "onClick" event in the botton of the page. I need to create my own function and call $.ajax manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to the comment of Stu, I've changed the concept of solution:

First of all, I've create a static link without using any component:

```
<a href="#" id="addButton" onClick="addRow()">Aggiunti con Link</a>
```

And then, I've created a specific function that is not other that what AjaxLink/AjaxButton do secretely:

```
<script>
            function addRow(){
                var indexValue = $('#currentRowId').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                        'method':'get',
                        'data':{'index':indexValue},
                        'success':function(data){
                                $('#tableBody').append(data);
                           $('#currentRowId').val(parseInt($('#currentRowId').val(),10)+1);
                         },
                         'url':'<?php echo CController::createUrl('users/AddRow'); ?>',
                         'cache':false});
            }

        </script>
```